# the extension to upload a file in postman is not validated

Tags: node.js, api, validation, file-upload, postman

[image]

I am doing a project with node js, I am in the part of uploading images, I made a function to validate the file extensions that can be uploaded. The problem is when I upload the file it always returns the same message:

`{ "message": "No file has been uploaded" }`

and although it returns the message it puts the image in the indicated path, it only validates when I enter a correct token as authorization but even if I put a different id in the url to upload the image it performs the action and returns the same message.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where's the code and wheres your request? We can guess it.

Comment: I put pictures of the post man request and in an answer is the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict'
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-pagination');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('../services/jwt');
//Métodos de prueba
function home (req, res){
    res.status(200).send({
        message: 'Acción de pruebas en el servidor de NodeJs'
    });
}
function pruebas(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send({
        message: 'el estatuto n212 rige al universo'
    });
}
//Registro de usuario
function saveUser(req, res){
    var params = req.body;
    var user = new User();

    if(params.name && params.surname && 
        params.nick && params.email && params.password){
            user.name = params.name;
            user.surname = params.surname;
            user.nick = params.nick;
            user.email = params.email;
            user.role = 'ROLE_USER';
            user.image = null;

            //Control de usuarios duplicados
            User.find({$or: [
                               {email: user.email.toLowerCase()},
                               {nick: user.nick.toLowerCase()}
                            ]}).exec((err, users) => {
                                if(err) return res.statur(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición usuario'})
                                if(users && users.length >= 1){
                                    return res.status(200).send({message: 'El usuario ya existe'})
                                }else{
                                    bcrypt.hash(params.password, null, null, (err, hash) => {
                                        user.password = hash;
                                        user.save((err, userStored) => {
                                            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar usuario'});
                                            if(userStored){
                                                res.status(200).send({user: userStored});
                                            } else {
                                                res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha registrado el usuario'});
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Debes llenar todos los campos.'
        });
    }
}
//Login de usuario
function loginUser(req, res){
    var params = req.body;
    var email = params.email;
    var password = params.password;

    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});

        if(user){
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, check) => {
                if(check){
                    //devolver datos de usuario
                    if(params.gettoken){
                        //genera y devuelve token
                        return res.status(200).send({
                            token: jwt.createToken(user)
                        });
                    }else{
                        //devuelve datos de usuario
                    }
                    user.password = undefined;
                    return res.status(200).send({user})
                }else{
                    return res.status(404).send({message: 'Credenciales inválidas'});
                }
            });
        }else{
            return res.status(404).send({message: 'Credenciales inválidas!!'});
 
        }
    });
}

// Obtener datos de UN usuario
function getUser(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;

    User.findById(userId, (err, user)=>{
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message:'Error en la petición'});
        if(!user) return res.status(404).send({message: 'El usuario no existe'});

        return res.status(200).send({user});
    });
}

// Devuelve una lista de usuarios paginadas
function getUsers(req, res){
    var identity_user_id = req.user.sub;
    var page = 1;
    if(req.params.page){
        page = req.params.page;
    }
    var itemsPerPage = 5;
    User.find().sort('_id').paginate(page, itemsPerPage, (err, users, total) =>{
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});
        if(!users) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No hay usuarios disponiles'});
        
        return res.status(200).send({
            users,
            total,
            pages: Math.ceil(total/itemsPerPage)
        });
    });
}

//Edición de datos de usuario
function updateUser(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;
    var update = req.body;

    // borrar propiedad password
    delete update.password;
   
    if(userId != req.user.sub){
        return res.status(500).send({message: 'No es posible actualizar los datos del usuario'});
    }
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, update, {new:true},(err, userUpdated) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});
        if(!userUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha podido actualizar el usuario'});
        
        return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated});
    });
}

//Subir archivos de imagen de usuario
function uploadImage(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;
  

    if(req.file){
        var file_path = req.file.image.path;
        console.log(file_path);
       
        var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
        console.log(file_split);

        var file_name = file_split[1];
        console.log(file_name);

        var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
        console.log(ext_split);

        var file_ext = ext_split[1].toLowerCase();
        console.log(file_ext);
    
        if(userId != req.user.sub){
         removeFilesOfUploads(res, file_path, 'No tienes permiso para modificar el archivo');
     }
    
     if(file_ext == 'png' || file_ext == 'jpg' || file_ext == 'jpeg' || file_ext == 'gif'){
        //Actualizar atributo de usuario logueado
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {image: file_name}, {new: true}, (err, userUpdated) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});
           
            if(!userUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha podido actualizar la foto'});
            
            return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated});  
        });
    }else{
         removeFilesOfUploads(res, file_path, 'Extensión no válida');
    }

    }else{
        return res.status(200).send({message: 'No se ha subido ningún archivo'});
    }
}

function removeFilesOfUploads(res, file_path, message){
    fs.unlink(file_path, (err) => {
        return res.status(200).send({message: message});
    });
}
module.exports = {
    home,
    pruebas,
    saveUser,
    loginUser,
    getUser,
    getUsers,
    updateUser,
    uploadImage
}
```

> Blockquote